# PDO query like always

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In my class 'uzytkownikclass.php' i have a variable which is called '$handler'. That variable store connection with my MySQL database. Before, i created few methods that query database for data. Those functions are working fine. But i created a new method called 'hasRole' which check user role (Administator, moderator etc). But i have a error, PDO is new for me and i can not fix this alone.
Here is my code:

```
public function hasRole()
{
  $email=$_SESSION['email_session'];
$stmt = $this->handler->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users INNER JOIN rolausera ON users.id = idusera INNER JOIN rola ON idroli = rola.id WHERE email = :email AND rola.id = :rola");
  $stmt->bindValue(':email',$email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindValue(':rola',$rola, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute(); 
  $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
  if($result[0]>0)
  {
    return TRUE;
  }
  else
  {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

Here is an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in D:\Programy\XAMPP\htdocs\logic\uzytkownikclass.php on line 120
```

As i said before, i have working methods:

```
$stmt = $this->handler->prepare("SELECT id, login, email, haslo FROM users WHERE email=:email1 ");
      $stmt->execute(array(':email1'=>$email1));
      $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and here is my connection method:

```
public $handler;
public function connection()
{
  $this->handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog', 'root', '',array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
  if($this->handler==false)
  {
    echo 'Blad';
  }

}
```

I tried to delete relation in query and use simple 'SELECT * FROM user' and i had same error.
Greetings.

Comment: it's a variable scope issue. Run it without your custom function and *magic* may very well happen.

Comment: Fine. I just added $handler1 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog', 'root', '',array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'")); and i used this as my handler variable. But why i can`t use my old handler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is: did you call the connection() method **before** calling the hasRole(), or perhaps you closed the connection somewhere in your code? Anyway, I would check in all methods, that try to query the database, if the connection is established and call the connection() method if not. Php's `is_null()` function helps determining if a variable has been set. I would also check if $handle is false.

Comment: uhm. i never closing connections in my scripts. And yeah, my handler is false because i added IF statement in my new method 'hasRole'.
   if(!$this->handler)
    {
      echo 'blad z baza';
    }
    else
    {
query etc.
}

Comment: But have you opened the connection before calling hasRole()?

Comment: Jesus, i swear. I had this connection before... Nevermind, you have a right. Maybe i did not saved a file and made Ctrl+Z. You deserve for best answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think it's a problem with PHP 5.6 [Beta]. 
Check your active PHP version, if you have PHP 5.6 [Beta], change to 5.4.

I haved the same problem, a class for connection with PDO working fine,  and without changes into the code, this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in...

For experience, when i have these errors, i see into my PHP version. On my case the hosting changes the PHP version without advise :(

See: [PHP bugs](https://bugs.php.net/search.php?limit=30&order_by=id&direction=DESC&cmd=display&status=Open&bug_type=All&phpver=5.6)